# How to position two <div> elements to share the same vertical align?

Tags: html, css

I have **#archive** and **#aboutGame** nested in the same section tag and wanted those two containers to share horizontal line.

In other words - I wanted **#archive** to remain beside the content of **#aboutGame**. Evidently, this text and image are pushed downwards because I could not position them vertically with **#archive**.

```css
#pageMain {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutGame {
  float: right;
  width: 430px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#aboutGame span {
  width: ;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#archive ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section id="pageMain">
  <div id="archive">
    <ul>
      <li>MARCH - 2018</li>
      <li>FEBUARY - 2018</li>
      <li>JANUARY - 2018</li>
      <li>DECEMBER - 2017</li>
      <li>NOVEMBER - 2017</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutGame">
    <span>
   As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith, or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
    <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" height="500px" width="800px" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `#pageMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}` this is supported by all browsers

Check this

```css
#pageMain {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

#aboutGame {
  width: 430px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#aboutGame span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#archive ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section id="pageMain">
  <div id="archive">
    <ul>
      <li>MARCH - 2018</li>
      <li>FEBUARY - 2018</li>
      <li>JANUARY - 2018</li>
      <li>DECEMBER - 2017</li>
      <li>NOVEMBER - 2017</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutGame">
    <span>
   As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith, or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
    <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" height="500px" width="800px" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Appears that the -float: right- position is affected. Any idea to resolve it too?

Comment: so you want the `#archive` to stay to the right all the time or to the left ? @LeqsoBezarashvili

Comment: add `justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;` to #pageMain as flex-start will keep both aligned left and align-items will vertical aligned them.

I edited the code

Answer (score 1):

Guide me from here, I got both your `div` next to each other.

```css
#pageMain {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

#aboutGame {
  flex: 1;
  width: 430px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#aboutGame span {
  width: ;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height:auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#archive {
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
}

#archive ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section id="pageMain">
  <div id="archive">
    <ul>
      <li>MARCH - 2018</li>
      <li>FEBUARY - 2018</li>
      <li>JANUARY - 2018</li>
      <li>DECEMBER - 2017</li>
      <li>NOVEMBER - 2017</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutGame">
    <span>
   As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith, or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
    <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" height="500px" width="800px" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add CSS**

#pageMain {

```
     display: table;
```

}

#archive, #aboutGame {

```
    display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just make following changes to your CSS and it will work:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#pageMain {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#pageMain div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#aboutGame {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrathod101/wegjyosj/2/) for your reference:

Answer (score -1):

Use Bootstrap.
add this in head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

The css.

```
#pageMain {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;    
}
#aboutGame {
  padding: 10px;
}
#aboutGame span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
#archive ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

And the HTML

```
  <section id="pageMain">
      <div id="archive" class="col-lg-6">
        <ul>
          <li>MARCH - 2018</li>
          <li>FEBUARY - 2018</li>
          <li>JANUARY - 2018</li>
          <li>DECEMBER - 2017</li>
          <li>NOVEMBER - 2017</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="aboutGame" class="col-lg-6">
        <span>
                As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith, or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
        <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" height="500px" width="800px" />
      </div>
    </section>
```